# How do I allow non-root access to /ttyUSB0?

Tags: usb, root

Since I updated from Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), I am unable to access the device connected in /ttyUSB0 if I don't have root access.

To be more specific, I use a USB-to-serial com port converter to access and configure Cisco equipment with software called [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY). It happens that, since I upgraded to 12.04, PuTTY only sees the connected device when I run it as `gksudo putty`. If not, it says "unable to connect to port /ttyUSB0".

I have managed to change the permissions via `chmod 666`, and it works, but if I disconnect the USB device and reconnect, it goes back to root only. How do I permanently allow non-root access? I have a clue it might be via [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules, but I have *no idea* how to do it.

Obs.: Manufacturer and drivers are "PROLIFIC"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible this is related to **modemmanager**, [as detailed here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/662881).

I removed that (`sudo apt-get remove modemmanager`) and it fixed my problem.

You still need to be in the `dialout` group though.

Comment: What if I can't remove modemmanager? I have a friend that has a 3G modem, and it seems he can't remove modemmanager because of that. How can he access /ttyUSB0 on 12.04 without root, but without removing modemmanager?

Comment: You can try by stopping it? `sudo stop modemmanager` It worked for me.

Comment: Been a few years, but this is still the case in Ubuntu 17.10.  Had to do a `sudo apt-get purge modemmanager` before `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` had the desired effect.

Comment: **Please note:**  being in `dialout` group is sufficient if you do not use `modemmanager` in any way.  The `modemmanager` removal is very case-specific to OPs situation, and is not a requirement every time.

Comment: Thank you bro. That solved my problem. I got access denied fron non-root user while the permission of `/dev/ttyUSB0` was 777 !

Answer (score 157):

The device is most likely attached to user group `dialout`.

To find out which user group the device is attached to:

```
stat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This should produce something like

```
Gid: (   20/ dialout)
```

Just add your user to the dialout group so you have appropriate permissions on the device.

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

(You may need to logout and back in for the new group to take effect.)

No need to mess around with permissions or udev rules.

Comment: no success... still no acces to ttyUSB0 without root... any other ideas???

Comment: Great, works fine for me.. thanks! sudo usermod -a -G dialout pier

Comment: @tom-hennen I guess you should add it first as a comment rather than edit it directly.

Comment: This doesn't work for Debian

Comment: @mike that is why we do not support debian ;) and in 2012 this did work for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind It was just a comment. I wasn't complaining or anything.

Comment: This worked perfect for me using Linux Mint, thanks!

Comment: Kudos for including "may need to logout and back in".

Comment: In Ubuntu (I'm on 18.04), logout/login doesn't work. we have to reboot after doing usermod.

Comment: Using `newgrp dialout` is enough to test the new permission in a shell, without having to logout.

Comment: With Kali linux after that I can only read from serial port, but not write.

Comment: UPD: The problem was - for another user (non-root) the minicom was set up incorrectly.

Comment: For some reason this didnt work for me... I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. What i did was a crontab that runs every minute that does the command chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0 ...

Comment: @RaulChiarella no please no. ANYONE even from the outside could address this device.  If the owner is not dialout change my command to what group is is; the method I posted -must- work cuz that is how groups work. If you do stick to chmod do 770 never 777.

Comment: Oh... But there is'nt anything i can do, besides, the system doesnt connect at all to the internet. Its a local system only that uses only local connection to connnect to local servers...

Comment: This answer should show up when googling for 'FTDI ubuntu not working', or 'FTDI ubuntu permission denied'. Would have saved me an hour :).

Comment: The answer would be better if it included a way to check to see what user group the device is attached to.

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo adduser <the user you want to add> dialout
sudo reboot
```

Mentioned by "Try now" worked for me. Check that You have `dialout` as group for `ttyUSB0`:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

in my case the output is:

```
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 12 12:01 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: in Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon I get this error when calling ' ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0 '  ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB0': No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

As [reported by Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/a/133244/22949), start by typing:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

But that is only part of the solution, as then you must reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: 1) Please don't post comments as answers. 2) No need to reboot; just log out and log back in.

Comment: I had to reboot to get this to work. A Logoff didn't propagate the change.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo adduser <the user you want to add> dialout
sudo reboot
id -Gn
```

Try now.

Answer (score 3):

I tried both

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER #(worked perfectly)
```

And `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0` (worked but had to type the command again)

I also removed the mode manager but did not really help. 
Therefore, the best command that worked for me was

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I had to add myself to the tty group.

I got hinted by the minicom command output:

```
minicom  /dev/ttyUSB0
minicom: cannot open /dev/tty8: Permission denied


ls -la /dev/tty8
crw--w---- 1 root tty 4, 8 juil. 31 08:27 /dev/tty
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because in this particular situation `minicom` application also opens `/dev/tty8` which is handled by entirely different group than `dialout`. Issue isn't directly related to `/dev/ttyUSB0` in this particular scenario and adding to `dialout` group won't fix the problem.  But it does prevent one from using `/dev/ttyUSB0` , hence it is one of the possible answers to the question

Comment: Checking the group associated to `/dev/ttyUSB0` (group `uucp` on Arch Linux) and adding my user to that group was the solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with /dev/ttyS0 in Mint Rosa.  Adding the user to the dialout group is required but in my case the device access was restricted and I had to expand it to give r/w access to group level also.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 18.04:

1. `sudo adduser <user> dialout`
2. **Full reboot**, for some reason mere logout/login is not sufficient ([bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtkterm/+bug/1828819)).

Answer (score -5):

navigate to /etc/ folder and edit the group file
add your username like this  `dialout:x:20:USER`

worked perfect for me :)

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to edit these files directly as some simple mistakes can cause loss of access.