# How to connect/read/write to serial port without root

Tags: permissions, root, serial-port, putty, minicom

As in the title, plus I'm already in group `dialout` via:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout ben
```

(I restarted my PC several times since then...)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

File permission of the device-file:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 216, 0 Aug 26 22:50 /dev/rfcomm0
```

when I try to run:`minicom` or `putty` (as `ben`, not as `root`)
I got following error:

```
minicom: Error opening the file »/dev/rfcomm0«: The device or ressource is busy
```

(same with `putty`)

But when I do: **`sudo minicom`**, everything is OK and works well.

(Device seems not to be busy anymore, when using sudo)

**Question:**
How to connect/read/write to serial port **without `root`**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question.
To solve the problem, I had to remove the **modemmanager** via:

```
sudo apt remove modemmanager
```

After a reboot, `minicom` (and `putty`) works without `root`!

Of course, you also need to be in the `dialout` group:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

I found the solution in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/155376/358044) and [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/662881).

Comment: This applies to Ubuntu 16.04 as well.