# Problem when using screen on /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: screen, tty

```
$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
[screen is terminating]
```

When I input command above, the output is really strange as below.

[image: Picture]

I just want to connect an USRP device. Could somebody tell me the reason for this output?

Comment: You do not need to use  `sudo`. You should add your user to `dialout` group (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/133244/66509)). Then you should check that hardware serial is really on /dev/ttyUSB0, as it may be on /dev/ttyACM0 (or with other numbers). Remove your USB adapter, open terminal with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, connect adaptop and check log for serial converters.

Comment: I am sorry to reply  late. I try to commond /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyACM0, the results are both no such file or directiory. I couldn't find this file in my computer either. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a disconnect between what you think screen does and what it actually does. screen creates **virtual** terminals. It looks to me like you are attempting to connect screen to an **actual** terminal via a USB serial port. The reason you are getting the error you receive is that screen is attempting to execute the program `/dev/ttyUSB0` and then get out of your way. This may be occurring because `/dev/ttyUSB0` does not exist as a device on your system. You can determine whether the device you are attempting to connect to exists by issuing the command `ls /dev/ | grep ttyUSB0`. No output means not there. For more on screen see either the the [help page,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) the [project page](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/screen), or `man screen`. You might also benefit from [this page](http://aperiodic.net/screen/) which includes links to some handy tutorials.

Comment: I am sorry to reply late. Actually there is no output after the command ls /dev/ | grep ttyUSB0. I change the language and it shows no such file or directory. I try to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Always glad to help. Since you are a new user, the way we say thanks here is by upvoting/accepting the answer that was most helpful to us. I believe that [this approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment) is true of all the [StackExchange websites.](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users)