# How can I automatically launch GPSD on startup?

Tags: 16.04, configuration

I am trying to figure out, what is preventing `gpsd` from automatically connecting to an external GPS BU 353 dongle via USB and receiving data. I have the same issue on both of my laptops (with different hardware), so this is purely a software configuration issue.

I have managed to get `gpsd` working manually, using the following steps, but every time my machine is powered off, I must go through these steps again.

1. `sudo killall gpsd`
2. Remove any sockets `gpsd` might have left behind with :

   sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock
3. Check the device path:

   ```
   dmesg - which shows PLU353
   ```
4. Ensure no other programs are using the device. There are none listed

   ```
   lsof -n | grep /dev/ttyUSB0
   ```
5. Manually launch `gpsd`:

   ```
   sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
   ```
6. `xgps` sees the GPS output - so this works

My best guesses are that `gpsd` needs to join a group or be given additional permissions, or alternatively, that it is an issue with `udev` configuration. But I am blundering about in the dark, just making wild guesses.

Comment: Rather than `lsof -n | grep /dev/ttyUSB0`, I'd use `sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0` - no need to `grep`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I allow non-root access to /ttyUSB0 on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133235/how-do-i-allow-non-root-access-to-ttyusb0-on-12-04)

Comment: This has 2 answers from high-reputation (~20k) users, and it still hasn't been edited! Guys - tidy it up when you answer, it's a key part of keeping this site high-quality! @waltinator, remember to try to fix *everything* in the question when you edit it!

Answer (score 8):

You're correct - it is a group membership problem. First, see who owns the device:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

On MY system, I don't have `/dev/ttyUSB0`, so I'll use `/dev/ttyS0` instead

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Feb 23 08:19 /dev/ttyS0
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

The output of the `ls` command shows that it's owned by `root:dialout`, and allows group access to the device.

Add your user to the `dialout` (or whatever is right for your system) group with:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Then to make this group membership take effect, logout/login, OR `newgrp dialout` to start a shell with that group membership.

Check your group membership with `/usr/bin/id`.

Comment: Hi Waltinator, I have run and get the same output ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0 giviing crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 24 19:10 /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: Additionally, I am in the dialout group as I just posted and I also tried adding gpsd into the dialout group as well and rebooting, but no joy

Answer (score 5):

- open TCP port 2947 in your firewall (*if you wish other network clients access*)
- in `terminal`...
- `sudo adduser $USER dialout` # add user to group dialout

  - log out/in to finish adduser command
- `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/gpsd` # edit the gpsd settings file

---

```
# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
# DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
DEVICES=""

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS=""
```

---

- save file and quit gedit
- `sudo systemctl restart gpsd` # restart gpsd

gpsmon, cgps, and xgps will now work properly.

Comment: Wrong device name, and from what can be seen in first post, he doesn't have to open any ports for it to work; only re-start gpsd as root.

Comment: @vidarlo fixed. Thanks! The open port IS required if you want any of the gps software to find the daemon output.

Comment: No, not unless you have modified `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, which by default allows all on `lo` interface. In addition, it should be noted that gpsd may use a socket as well, which does not touch the network stack at all. As I stated; in the question it works *after* restarting gpsd, without any modification to the firewall rules.

Comment: @vidarlo ok... educate me... where is there any documentation about modifying `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, and what would you modify there? Also, re: tcp port... "Client applications will communicate with gpsd via a TCP/IP port, 2947 by default)".

Comment: `/etc/ufw/before.rules` contains iptables rules that are applied *before* any user rules in UFW. `man ufw` shows some information. You **do not** need to modify anything there, as **all** traffic over loopback is allowed by default rule set. Communication with gpsd running on the same machine happens either via socket or loopback, both which bypass any firewall rules. Again, please read the question; he gets it working **witout** modifying firewall rules. It is a device permission problem. If you come by [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) I'll elaborate.

Comment: Hi All, I have only just seen all your responses, thank you all very much, I will work through them and report back

Comment: as a new user, it looks like I have only 16 points and I can not o

Comment: post on the forum until I have 20 point, which is frustrating, as I can see the thread, but can not interact with you guys............

Comment: @Geoffrey-c I do see your comments :-)

Comment: i am replying use comments, not via the chat room, but I am glad you can see me

Comment: so, it looks like I have to add gpsd to the dialout group, is this right? I have added myself to that group, as per the gpsd tutorial.

Comment: @Geoffrey-c if you've added yourself to the dialout group, that should be all you need.

Comment: Hi Heynnema, sadly not, I have checked, I get geoffrey adm uucp dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
I just added gpsd to diallout and rebooted, that has made no difference - I get gpsd : dialout
Someone else mentioned tty group , perhaps I have to add gpsd or me to that group as well

Comment: Did you logout/login, or reboot, after adding your_username to group dialout? I'm no expert here... and I'm playing with gpsd right now myself, to refresh my memory on how I got it to work here. Sorry I can't be of more help right now. Did you edit /etc/default/gpsd and edit the DEVICES= line for the correct device?

Comment: Hi Heynnema, sorry to be such a pain, but on 14.4 this was all pretty much plug and play and all the documentation says that it still is, but clearly its not LOL yes, I added myself to dialout months back and of course have logged in and out many times. I am afraid of editing etc/default/gpsd unless we are very clear on what we are doing, because I havent a clue about how to do that

Comment: Show me `ls /dev | grep -i ttyUSB` and `grep -i DEVICES /etc/default/gpsd`.

Comment: Hi Heynnema, I hope I have done that right, here is the return   Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
DEVICES=""

Comment: @Geoffrey-c you didn't show me the ls command output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90173/discussion-between-geoffrey-c-and-heynnema).

Comment: I've just tried this on Ubuntu 20.04 with lsusb showing my GPS device. I've amended /etc/default/gpsd to have DEVICES="/dev/ttyS0".
I used /dev/ttyS0 as "On MY system, I don't have /dev/ttyUSB0, so I'll use /dev/ttyS0 instead".
sudo systemctl status gpsd gave:
● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; disabled; vendor preset>
cgps shows latitude etc as N/A.
Light on device flashes red & green alternately.
Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnRose Enable the gpsd.service then start it. `sudo systemctl enable gpsd` and `sudo systemctl start gpsd`. Otherwise, make sure to follow my instructions in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Did as instructed. Same result for cgps.

Comment: @JohnRose Please start a new question. Include `cat /etc/default/gpsd` and `systemctl status gpsd` and `ls /dev`. Let me know the new question # and I'll take a look.

Comment: @heynnema I have the info requested by when I start  anew question, there is no icon to attach files. How do I attach files to a question?

Comment: @JohnRose You don't attach files to a question. You copy/paste from the terminal, into the question that you're editing, and then click the {} icon to format it into human-readable text.

Comment: When I copy/paste into a comment on the question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413674/gps-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04 there is no {} icon.

Comment: Managed to do the {} function but it looks a mess. Is there a reason why askubuntu does not have the facility to attach files?