# Have to take ownership of USB port after each reboot

Tags: permissions, tty, chown, ownership

I have a laser engraver. I was having issues getting Ubuntu to talk to it via USB.  I finally sorted that out, but now when I reboot, I have to run the command below every time, or I can't talk to the engraver.  What am I missing so it will stay permanently?  Thanks.

```
sudo chown [username] ttyUSB0
```

Comment: To correct method is to add yourself to the group of ttyUSB0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I allow non-root access to /ttyUSB0?](https://askubuntu.com/a/133244/66509) .

Answer (score 2):

ttyUSB is a serial connection. It should be available. You might have to change the user rights:

```
sudo adduser <user> dialout
```

where your username should replace "< user >"